# Spread operator on a component disables the react/prop-types rule on eslint-config-airbnb

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes, eslint-config-airbnb

The problem that I'm facing is that when I add the spread attributes in a component then the react/prop-types rule stops working:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import Button from './Button';

const LoginFacebook = ({
      label, ...props
    }) => (
      <Button
        {...props} // if I remove this line then eslint shows me the react/proptypes error
      >
        {label}
      </Button>
    );
```

.eslintrc:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "max-len": ["error", { "code": 80, "ignoreUrls": true }],
    "no-console": [2]
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  }
}
```

.package.json

```
"eslint": "^4.19.1",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
```

and this is how I'm using this component in Login Container:

```
...    
render() {
       return (
        <Grid>
          <GridCell span="6" phone="4" tablet="8">
            <LoginFacebook
              onLoginSuccess={this.onLoginSuccess}
              onLoginFailure={this.onLoginFailure}
            />
          </GridCell>
        </Grid>
       )
    }
```

Comment: please provide the codes of parent component of the `LoginFacebook` component, I think I can help

Comment: you mean the import files? the Button component is just a simple button tag

Comment: the Button component is the child of the LoginFacebook component. Please provide the parent of the LoginFacebook component in the component tree cuz I just want to see how you pass data to the LoginFacebook component.

Comment: ah, ok no problem thanks for your help

Comment: It looks like you do not pass down any props call "label", right?

Comment: The label in this case is in the LinkedinButton defaultProps, the funny thing is that when I add the spread attributes to the Button component then the eslint linter doesn’t give me an error, that the prop needs a proptype

Comment: It seems it has been fixed with eslint-plugin-react v7.12.0+ see https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/pull/1939 and https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/pull/1939 for more information